# GNSS accuracy, what is it?

Tags: gps, accuracy, trimble

Using a Trimble GeoExplorer 6000 Series GeoXT Handheld, I recorded uncorrected GNSS positions, for example:

Horizontal estimated accuracy in the field `4` meters.
Vertical estimated accuracy in the field `10` meters.
Position Dilution of Precision `PDOP = 2`

1. Am I correct in saying that these accuracies are specified as RMS and have `68%` vertical confidence and a `63–68%` horizontal confidence?
2. Is this accuracy `±`? For example, is the horizontal accuracy `±4m` or is it `4m` across `= ±2m`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The precision of GNSS devices is indeed usually given in RMS. Trimble is not an exception. In your case, you would have 63% of confidence that your point is located within an horizontal circle of radius 4 m around the measured position. And 68% confidence that your elevation is within +/- 10 m from the measured one. PDOP of 2 is quite good, so you can expect submetric precision after corrections.

As a remark, make sure that the elevation is in an appropriate elevation datum, because this could be an important source of inaccurate measurement.